# Align data points InfluxDB2

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm gathering the in_octects from 2 switches. The problem is that one switch is giving me a result some seconds before the other and this is a problem if want to sum the total in_octects of both switches because the result is an up and down between the 2 values instead of a line higher than the other 2.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to align these 2 values?

Query to get values separated between switches:

```
from(bucket: "ACIG")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop) 
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "interfacesState")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "counters/in_octets")
  |> toInt() 
  |> group(columns: ["source"]) 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "sum")
```

Query to get the aggregate value (blue line):

```
from(bucket: "ACIG")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "interfacesState")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "counters/in_octets")
  |> toInt() 
  |> group(columns: ["_measurement"])
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: sum, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "sum")
```